# How to convert String and perform calculation in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a string as: 
*"I have 67+89.06 Dollars."*

Now I want to do calculation and update the string as: 
*"I have 156.06 Dollars."*

Using Swift how can I perform this task?

The numbers in the raw string can be any value and not just what i wrote above.

Comment: No buddy. I'm working on a project by myself.

Comment: What didn't work when you tried implementing a solution for this? Where were you struggling? Please show your attempt.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. Well i know how to convert numbers to strings and vice versa, but extracting only numbers and performing calculations as required and updating the string again is very difficult for me, I'm unable to think of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to read the Apple docs at developer.apple.com

```
 "I have 67+89.06 Dollars."
   // In order to get a Float value both operands need to be of type Float. 
     let valueCalculate = "I have \(Float(67) +   Float((89.06))) Dollars"
print(valueCalculate)

// Convert String to Int
 var stringNumber = "123456"
  var convertToInt = Int(stringNumber)

 // Convert Float value to Int
   var stringNumber = "123456"
    var convertToInt = Int(stringNumber)

  //convert value of type Float written as a String to Float
     var stringWithFloatValue = "123.250"
     var stringtoFloatValue = Float(stringWithFloatValue)

    //convert Float value to Int
    if stringtoFloatValue != nil {
       let floatToInt = Int(stringtoFloatValue!)
 }
```

Comment: @Mohit Mishra   You need to know what type of value your user sends you and then convert the values to the appropriate type you are looking for. In your example you have values of type Int and Float, in order to perform a calculation you need to convert them all either to Int values or Float values. I suggest you  keep your values in Float if your user is allowed to enter values manually in a field and also do some type of checking on the values entered in the fields. You could expect to receive a Float or Int value, but your user will send you a value "393er%&" and your app will crash.

Comment: @MohitMishra   I suggest you start from here   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html